# How to generate a random string in C++

Tags: c++, string, random

After quite a few hours of screwing around I can't seem to figure out how to make a random string generator in C++. I was wondering if you could show me how you would go about doing this.

Comment: Take a post from SO with a person without any reputation or posting any code?!

Comment: Please be more specific? Do you want to generate a randomly selected word from some dictionary? Or do you just want a random sequence of characters? If the later, how many characters? Ie how long do you want your "random" string to be? Etc.

Comment: I want to generate from a set of characters. In this case I am using a-z, both lowercase and uppercase, and I am also using 0-9. The length of the string doesn't matter because I was hoping to make the length interchangeable.

Comment: @user3280728 - What code have you come up so far?

Comment: Given `char distinct_chars[] = "abcd...xyz0123456789";`, loop however-many times appending `distinct_chars[rand() % sizeof distinct_chars]`.  You may want to read about `srand` too (call it once atop `main()`).

Comment: void RandomPassword::generateRandomNumber(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int randomNumber;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        randomNumber = rand() % 62;
        password += charset[randomNumber];
    }
}

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but it sounds like you want something along these lines:

```
const std::string VALID_CHARS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,VALID_CHARS.size() - 1);

std::ostringstream oss;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < SOME_SIZE; ++i)
{
    oss << VALID_CHARS[distribution(generator)];
}
std::string your_random_string = oss.str();
```

You can simplify it a bit by replacing the loop:

```
const std::string VALID_CHARS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,VALID_CHARS.size() - 1);
std::string your_random_string;
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(your_random_string), SOME_SIZE, [&]()
{
    return VALID_CHARS[distribution(generator)];
});
```

Also, if you can use C++11, avoid using the C standard library functions (`srand` and `rand`) as the newer C++11 `<random>` library gives much more control over the types of random number generators and distributions for those generators.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it easily with a [`generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) and a custom lambda:

```
string generateRandomString(size_t length)
{
  const char* charmap = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  const size_t charmapLength = strlen(charmap);
  auto generator = [&](){ return charmap[rand()%charmapLength]; };
  string result;
  result.reserve(length);
  generate_n(back_inserter(result), length, generator);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly work out how to create a random character of the distribution you want, and test this. In C and C++, a char is a type of integer, so you can just work with it as you would an integer. eg

```
char ch = 'A' + random()%26;
```

This takes the character A and adds a random number between 0 and 25.  You would need to adjust that to obtain the distribution of characters / digits / punctuation you need.  Your source of random numbers will vary according to the system library that you are using.

After you get a single character, just build them into a string as you normally would, with ostringstream, for example.